# Manage hierarchical data "error :REPEAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

I am beginner at SQL. I am doing research about managing hierarchical data by using ms sql r2 2008. Here is the link from where I referred 
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
But now I having a problem in **Finding the Depth of the Nodes**
I Copy the sql query to my ms sql

```
SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT(' ', COUNT(parent.name) - 1), node.name) AS name
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

It return me

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1 'REPEAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Can anyone please help me correct the sql query?
In addition, anyone got a better solution for manage hierarchical data?

Comment: in SQL Server you use `REPLICATE()` instead of `REPEAT()`

Comment: hi , i try repeat. but nw it return me 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: do `SELECT REPLICATE(' ', COUNT(parent.name) - 1) + node.name AS NAME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using code from a MySQL article on MS SQL Server.

Much will translate fine, but much won't.  As @FilipDeVos says, the equivilent to `REPEAT()` in SQL Server is `REPLICATE()`, and you're going to find many more cases like this.

When you find them, you need to search on line for the SQL Server equivilent to the MySQL statements that you are using.

As for different methods of managing hierarchies, the most common is probably adjaceny-lists, then nested-sets that you're using in that article.  It depends on your needs, keep researching, there is no universall golden answer.

**EDIT**

If you keep going through that article and ask here about every difference, you'll be here forever.  You need to search the web for your answers ;)

But, for now, after your added question about `CONCAT()`, try this...

```
SELECT REPLICATE(' ', COUNT(parent.name) - 1) + node.name AS name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think REPEAT is a mysql command, and you've tagged MSSSQL, so that probably won't work.

For hierarchical data in Sql Server 2008, look at the HierarchyId data type. I've added links to a couple of MSDN articles that should point you in the right direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a different syntax than mysql. The query can be rewritten as follows

```
SELECT REPLICATE(' ', COUNT(parent.name) - 1) + node.name AS name
  FROM nested_category AS node
  JOIN nested_category AS parent
    ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
 GROUP BY node.name
 ORDER BY node.lft;
```

- The `REPEAT()` function in MySQL can be replaced by the `REPLICATE()` function in SQL Server.
- The `CONCAT()` function in MySQL does not have a counterpart in SQL Server, but string concatenation can be done through the use of the `+` operand.
- A join in SQL Server can be better written with the `INNER JOIN` construction as it is more expressive (although the approach with the comma does work fine).